Unable to fetch RSSI and frequent disconnection in linux
I am observing a few issues in linux while the same piece of code works fine for windows:
Code To fetch RSSI:

Frequent disconnection of device.
Fetching RSSI is failing.
Unable to scan devices during on reconnection.

It seems like the BLE is unable to watch advertisements as there is no event arrival. However the same code works well for windows.
Also, when I try to reconnect using the  navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice() it shows no compatible devices and the re-scan button doesn't work. Click here for image
Any help is appreciated!
CODE TO FETCH RSSI:
let rssi;

function watchAdv() {
    abortController = new AbortController();
    device.addEventListener('advertisementreceived', handleAdvEvent);
    console.log("watching adv");

    device.watchAdvertisements({ signal: abortController.signal });

    const id = setTimeout(() => {
        rssi = 'Failed';
    }, 3000);

    return id;
}

function handleAdvEvent(event) {
    abortController.abort();
    rssi = event.rssi + " (before connection)";
    console.log("rssi:", rssi);
}


It is a known issue for Web Bluetooth on Linux that WatchAdvertisement isn't functional as no proper underlying system API for this support. This issue is being tracked by https://g-issues.chromium.org/issues/40233338.
